# Why does the Integer constructor method no longer require attributes?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When attempting to compile the following code:

```
public class IntTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = new Integer(5);
    }
}
```

The following error occurs:

```
 IntTest.java:3: error: constructor Integer in class Integer cannot be applied to given types;
    Integer i = new Integer(5);
                ^
  required: no arguments
  found: Integer
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

It therefore follows that you can only use `new Integer()` to initialize the variable, and cannot add the number as an attribute, e.g. `new Integer(5)`.

Why is Java using a different constructor than usual, that doesn't accept an attribute being included for `new Integer()`?

Comment: I don't get it; you're trying to pass in the variable you're trying to instantiate as an argument to what you're trying to instantiate?

Comment: Why are you attempting to initialize `i` by passing itself to the `Integer` constructor?  This gets me the compiler error "variable i might not have been initialized".

Comment: Aside from the typo where the code is attempting to initialise a variable using the variable, the issue was caused by another Integer class being located in the same folder, which means the java.lang.Integer class was not being used.
Removing Integer.class from the same folder resolved this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to initialize it on itself - you are passing `i` as an argument, not something like `5`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Integer(int value)
   Constructs a newly allocated Integer object that represents the specified int value.
```

this is the documentation of integer, you are passing and integer i that the current value is null, to a constructor that return and integer from and int value, the correct form will be like this

```
Integer i = new Integer(5);
```

and you are doing something like this

```
int i = i;
```

I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

Operator new returns a refernce to a memory block allocated to hold the object of type Integer, and then points i to that location. It calls the constructor of Integer class Integer() which looks like this:

```
public Integer(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

So from this, you see it sets the this.value to argument provided  to constructor. this is that refernce to the memory block that is provided to constructor.

From your code i don't see you instantiated i to any value, hence the error, because the compiler doesn't know what to assign to variable in the memory.